# Some UIButtons are hidden originally in custom TableViewCell and some are not, but on scrolling everything gets messed up

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In my application, on the basis of some data returned from web service, i have to disable or enable a button on custom `UITableViewCell`. Initially, when the Table is presented, everything is fine; but after scrolling things become out of hand.

I know i need to use tags. but how? Do i tag each cell or only the related button on each cell. Please help.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifierForContacts = @"UserContacts";
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            ContactNumberTableCell *cell = (ContactNumberTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierForContacts];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactNumberTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

// THE CALL BUTTON IS TO BE DISABLED WHEN THE WEB SERVICE DOES NOT RETURN A CONTACT NUMBER

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapForCall = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callPressed:)];
            [cell.call addGestureRecognizer:singleTapForCall];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapForSave = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(savePressed:)];
            [cell.save addGestureRecognizer:singleTapForSave];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [arrayOfContactNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

                if([dict objectForKey:@"WorkPhone"] == [NSNull null])
                {
                    cell.contactNumber.text = @"Not In Record";

//AREA OF PROBLEM.. THE STATE DOES NOT REMAIN THE SAME WHEN TABLE ROWS ARE SCROLLED

                        [cell.call setHidden:YES];
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        cell.contactNumber.text = [dict objectForKey:@"WorkPhone"];
                    }

}
```

Comment: would you show full code of `cellForRowAtIndexpath:`?

Comment: Actually, only this part of the code is relevant to my problem.. even if i paste the code here, it won't help..

Comment: actually, this line `if (!indexPath.row)` doesn't make sense. that's y i'm asking. How many time this line gets true? Have you check with that?

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
-  (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    //Your code
    --- 
    ----
                    if([dict objectForKey:@"WorkPhone"] == [NSNull null])
                    {
                        //AREA OF PROBLEM.. THE STATE DOES NOT REMAIN THE SAME WHEN TABLE ROWS ARE SCROLLE
                         cell.contactNumber.text = @"Not In Record";
                         [cell.call setHidden:YES];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          [cell.call setHidden:NO];//show your button here
                           cell.contactNumber.text = [dict objectForKey:@"WorkPhone"];
                      }
    //Your code
    --- 
    ----
        }
```

Comment: what did you get in this line `if (!indexPath.row)`. How many times it get true?

Comment: if(!indexPath.row) checks if the row is a section. Actually I am creating nested rows.. that is collapsable and expandable rows

Comment: yes it is working fine.. the problem is in maintaining the state of the buttons only..

Comment: Answer not helped you?